What is the purpose of a Community member “bumping” an old question and how is it done?
According to the Jehovah's Witnesses what form did God take at Acts 7:2?
This old CSE question, asked by Mr. Bond, has been “bumped” 5 times since it was originally asked:
July 2023, November 2023, 1 March 2024, 31 March 2024, 29 July 2024.
Why? And how is it done?

It's not always apparent why that kind of stuff happens, it's usually because a seemingly good question (+3) is effectively unanswered (only one answer with +1). You'll see it a lot more on the even more unpopular sites, I also moderate the devops stackexchange (which has a lot of traffic, but not a lot of usage) - that site has a quite a bit more community bumps

That is helpful, but how would I go about "bumping" a seemingly good question (+3) with only one answer (+1)?

@Lesley you can edit it (more than just grammar) - which is not a great way to bump it, or put a bounty on it, which is the preferred method

Ah, I understand.  If I edit a question it brings it to the top of the "active" question list.  If I place a bounty on it, it will possibly attract more answers.

"effectively unanswered (only one answer with +1)" the score was 0 at the time of bumping, which considered the question unanswered. Someone upvoted it after the bump.
